# Facing trouble locating unknown curl scripts/command responsible for calling API calls every few seconds on the EC2 Server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2

I am stuck in a super weird problem. I have a project running on NodeJs in EC2 instance, and I am using PM2 for running the project. Everything works fine but I see two api endpoints in our project getting called from some unknown place. Doing `cat /etc/crontab` lists no active cron jobs after doing ssh into this instance, neither the requests are coming from client side or any other AWS service like lambda or API Gateway.

The access to this server was given to us few months back and today we realized that there 2 of such endpoints which are getting called at every few intervals from a request of unknown origin. Also, due to some reasons, it is also not possible to contact the person who created this instance in the first place.

This is how the calls look in node project:

`GET /api/host/areas/cron 200 0.814 ms - 63`

`GET /api/host/areas/updateStatus 200 0.814 ms - 63`

`/cron` and `/updateStatus` are endpoints in our node project but none of them are called from our services as I explained above.

**What I tried:**

I did some research and tried to print the requests when the calls are made to this endpoint, and this is what the request headers looks like (I have changed the ip address value, axzn-trace-id and host values from below to keep details private):

```
{
0|npm            |   host: 'api.our-company.com',
0|npm            |   connection: 'close',
0|npm            |   'x-forwarded-for': '12.34.56.78' // (value changed, this shows our server ip),
0|npm            |   'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
0|npm            |   'x-forwarded-port': '443',
0|npm            |   'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
0|npm            |   'user-agent': 'curl/7.61.1',
0|npm            |   accept: '*/*'
0|npm            | }
```

So, it looks like these requests are getting called via some unknown Curl command which is maybe installed on our server and is calling the 2 endpoints in question at every few seconds like a scheduler.

**What I want:**

My question is how to know which commands are getting called and how to modify them? and where are the details of this command (if any) stored inside the ec2-instance?

**PS:** Please note that I don't wish to stop or delete these commands without first knowing its origin, I would then like to modify the frequency of calls and add more on top of it once I know how these calls are made.

I am struggling to solve this mystery from last 2-3 days, but no luck. Thank you.